# Getting error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit
Global glbUN As String
Global glbPWD As String
Global cnEDW As ADODB.Connection

Sub Teradata()
'Connects to Teradata
Call Open_EDWDatabase
DoEvents

'Close Teradata
Call Close_EDWDatabase
DoEvents

End Sub

Public Sub Open_EDWDatabase()

    Set cnEDW = New ADODB.Connection
    If glbUN = "" Or glbPWD = "" Then
        'Open login screen and center the form for people with 2 monitors
        UserForm1.StartUpPosition = 0
        UserForm1.Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * UserForm1.Width)
        UserForm1.Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * UserForm1.Height)
        UserForm1.Show 1
    End If

    cnEDW.ConnectionString = "Driver={Teradata};Persist Security Info=False;User ID=" & glbUN & ";Pwd=" & glbPWD & ";Data Source=teradata_PRD"
    cnEDW.Open

End Sub

Public Sub Close_EDWDatabase()

    cnEDW.Close
    Set cnEDW = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm getting

> Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)

running the above codes. Does anyone know why? I think the error happens at the UserForm row. Thank you in advance.

Comment: To troubleshoot this, first identify which line you get the error on.

Comment: I believe its at the UserForm row.

Comment: Why would the user creds need to be global-scoped?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: "you believe"? it will stop on the exact line and show you.

Comment: I modified the codes a little, and it stops at the userform row with error "variable not defined". Thanks

Comment: *Variable not defined* means that `UserForm1` is not visible in that sub. You can't use a variable that is not defined.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Ken! That exact same codes work in a different Excel file. So should I do something like Dim userform?

Comment: is the userform not part of the new excel file? it has to be in order to work.

Comment: I see ! I dragged the old userform to the new Excel file. It works now. Thank you everyone!